# Adding significance levels in faceted plots with two results in the same x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate, geom-text, ggpubr

I know that there are many questions already open to add significance level in ggplot2 in faceted plots. However, as a R beginner, I did not found a solution for my plot. 
My data (.txt file) is available in this link:

1drv.ms/t/s!AsLAxDXdkA9Mg8oXdJ-qxD5AeB4KAw

There are four columns: three factor levels (temperature, parasitoid species and behavior) and a numeric level (number of parasitism and host-killing).

I run the plot with the code:

```
    ggplot(mydata, aes(x = temperature, y = value, fill = species)) +  
facet_grid(. ~ behavior) +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge", stat="identity") +
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult = 1) +
labs(x = "Temperature", y = "Nº of parasitized or host-killed larvae") +
theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank(),  legend.text = element_text(size = 11, face = "italic"))
```

[image]

Now I want to add the significance level in each plot, comparing separately the results in Parasitism and Host-Killing in both temperatures. So I have 6 contrasts in each plot. I tested the option using the function stat_compare_means. However, as advised in this Rblogger tutorial (https://www.r-bloggers.com/add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/) I should make a list telling what I want to compare. But, in this case, I have two results  for 25°C and two for 30°C. How I could create this list mentioning all the contrasts? 
If anybody could clarify for me how I can solve this, it would help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: A reproducible example is usually expected when asking for help (because it leads to better quality answers).

Comment: Sorry, first time making a question here. My data (.txt format) is available in this link: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AsLAxDXdkA9Mg8oXdJ-qxD5AeB4KAw

Comment: You should review the question adding your data. Use edit for doing it.

Answer (score 2):

`stat_compare_means` worked "out of the box" (which makes sense, since it's using the grouping defined in the `ggplot` function.

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = temp, y = value, fill = factor(species))) +  
  facet_grid(. ~ behavior) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = position_dodge(width = 1), stat="identity") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom="errorbar", position = position_dodge(width = 1), width=0.25, stat="identity", fun.args = list(mult = 1)) +
                 labs(x = "Temperature", y = "Nº of parasitized or host-killed larvae") +
                 theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank(),  legend.text = element_text(size = 11, face = "italic")) + 
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test")
```

[image]

Alternatively, switch the x and fill variables:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = factor(species), y = value, fill = factor(temp))) +  
  facet_grid(. ~ behavior) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = position_dodge(width = 1), stat="identity") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom="errorbar", position = position_dodge(width = 1), width=0.25, stat="identity", fun.args = list(mult = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Temperature", y = "Nº of parasitized or host-killed larvae") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",  legend.text = element_text(size = 11, face = "italic")) + 
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @thc. This gave me results between the two parasitoids species at 25°C and 30°C. However, I would like also to have the results comparing the same species at 25°C and 30°C. Any alternative?

Comment: You could switch the x and fill variables, see edit.

Comment: It is also interesting, however, I still need to make pairwise test between the four results in each plot. In the tutorial I mentioned, it says to make a list as: my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") ) and then insert in: stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons). But How can I refer to each contrast, if I have 2 values in each temperature?

Comment: You're asking too much of the function.  Probably, it can't do what you ask -- how would it know where to put 8 comparisons on the plot?  If you need that much control, I'd suggest calculating the p-values outside of ggplot and using `geom_text`.

Comment: Yes, it would be 6 contrasts and probably the plot would get very messy. I tried using geom_text to insert siggnificance letters. In the first plot would be - a, a, b, b, and in the second A, B, C, C. However, I did not get right in this facet plot. The only way I made it was using the annotate function in a single plot, that I imagine it should have a better way.

Comment: Create a new data frame with text labels `sigvals <- data.frame(x=1,y=250, text=c("a,a,b,b","A,A,B,B"), behavior=c(1,2))` with facet column, then it will respect the facet.  Add `geom_text(data=sigvals, aes(x=x,y=y, label=text, fill=NA), hjust=0)` to the end of your ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @thc for your help and patience. As I decided  to use letters over the error bars, I had to create a new data.frame for each letter and them add the `geom_text`. This got it right with the below code, after testing many x and y values to insert the letters in the right point. But certainly it has an easier way to do it that I don't know it.

```
    sigvals1 <- data.frame(x=0.75,y=222.4, text=c("a"), behavior=c("Parasitism"))
    sigvals2 <- data.frame(x=1.207,y=190.55, text=c("a"), behavior=c("Parasitism"))
    sigvals3 <- data.frame(x=1.75,y=117.7, text=c("b"), behavior=c("Parasitism"))
    sigvals4 <- data.frame(x=2.209,y=103, text=c("b"), behavior=c("Parasitism"))
    sigvals5 <-data.frame(x = 0.75, y = 74.8, text=c("A"), behavior = c("Host-Killing"))
    sigvals6 <-data.frame(x = 1.20, y = 92.97, text=c("B"), behavior = c("Host-Killing"))
    sigvals7 <-data.frame(x = 1.74, y = 49.8, text=c("C"), behavior = c("Host-Killing"))
    sigvals8 <-data.frame(x = 2.196, y = 43, text=c("C"), behavior = c("Host-Killing"))

    plot + 
geom_text(data=sigvals1, aes(x=x,y=y, label=text, fill=NA), hjust=0) + 
      geom_text(data=sigvals2, aes(x=x,y=y, label=text, fill=NA), hjust=0) +
      geom_text(data=sigvals3, aes(x=x,y=y, label=text, fill=NA), hjust=0)+
      geom_text(data=sigvals4, aes(x=x,y=y, label=text, fill=NA), hjust=0) +
      geom_text(data=sigvals5, aes(x=x,y=y, label=text, fill=NA), hjust=0) +
      geom_text(data=sigvals6, aes(x=x,y=y, label=text, fill=NA), hjust=0) +
      geom_text(data=sigvals7, aes(x=x,y=y, label=text, fill=NA), hjust=0) +
      geom_text(data=sigvals8, aes(x=x,y=y, label=text, fill=NA), hjust=0)
```

Comment: Just noticed that adding the geom_text is inverting the sequence how the legend appears. Without adding, was first Opius scabriventris and second Chrysocharis vonones. Adding the geom_text it is the opposite now.  Any thoughts why this is happening?